# Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that for all $\varepsilon\in \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}, x< \varepsilon$. Argue by contradiction to show that $x\leq 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am new to Real Analysis.

Exercise: Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that for all $\varepsilon\in \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}$, we have $x< \varepsilon$. Argue by contradiction to show that $x\leq 0$.

My attempt:
Assume that $x\geq 0$. We have that for all $\varepsilon>0$, then $x< \varepsilon$. Let $\varepsilon = {x}/{n}$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>1$. It is given that $x< \varepsilon$, so $x< \varepsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $x< x/n$ $1<1/n$ which are false because we have $n>1$. Therefore, we have a contradiction so $x\leq 0$.

Do I miss something valid, or is this a sound proof.?

Comment: First of all, the opposite of $x\leq 0$ is $x>0$, not $x\geq 0$. So you need to assume $x>0$. Also, the proof will look a bit better if you choose some specific $n$. For example, you can simply take $\epsilon=\frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: @Mark, yeah thx! I meant ofc x>0.

Comment: Same 2 remarks as @Mark. Moreover, it would be smarter to stress that it is this hypothesis $x>0$ which allows you to deduce $1<1/n$ from $x<x/n.$

Answer (score -1):

Let's say that $x=\delta>0$, so for $\epsilon = \delta / 2$, we should have $$\delta = x < \epsilon = \delta / 2$$
That was a contradiction.